# How to search string for value using array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

**Hi!**
I want to search string having value like "CMS" in array $row, below code is searching for exact "CMS".

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0)
  { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
        { $counter++; 
           if (in_array("CMS", $row)) 
               { $cms++; }
          }
    }
```

I'll be  grateful if any one can guide me to how to search string for value LIKE "CMS" in array $row.

Comment: It will  more usefull to use SQL to count your data.

Comment: You'd better do the job with sql but not in php side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0)
  { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
        { $counter++; 
           if (strpos(serialize($row),"CMS")!==false)  //<--- Changed this `if` statement, nothing else
               { $cms++; }
          }
    }
```

You could `serialize` your array and then do a `strpos` to check whether the `needle` is inside the array or not. This is something similar like doing a `LIKE` as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each of the columns in the row and use `strpos`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) 
{ 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
    { 
        $counter++; 
        foreach($row as $column)
        {
            if (strpos($column, 'CMS'))
            {
                $cms++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0)
  { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
        { $counter++; 
           foreach ($row as $column) {
              if (strpos($column, "CMS") !== false) {
                  $cms++;
              }
           } 

        }
    }
```